# I have issue with python in my Uni project

Tags: python

sorry for asking this, this is my Uni project with python & I'm just learning python since a week, I tried a lot, I can't figure this out. Can anybody help me? please!

this is the sample code for the equation xdot=ax

[image]

so, I should write car cruise control in discrete with its equation below

the cruise control equation is: xdot=(c/m)u-gamma*x
where u is u=k(r-x)

and the discrete equation is

[image]

and finally this is my code but i get an error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

C      = 1
M      = 1
GAMMA  = 0.1
R      = 1
X0     = 0
TFINAL = 3
DT     = 0.1
t = np.arange(0, TFINAL, 0.1)
x = X0*np.exp(C*t)
td = np.arange(0, TFINAL, DT)
xd = np.zeros(len(td))
xd[0] = X0

for k in range(len(td)-1):
    u = k * (R - x)
    xd[k+1] = xd[k] + DT * (C / M * u - GAMMA * xd[k])

plt.plot(td,xd,'b-',label='approximate')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('x values')
plt.title('dynamical system: xdot=(c/m)u-gammax')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

the error is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e64edffca1fb> in <module>()
 10 for k in range(len(td)-1):
 11     u=k*(r-x)
---> 12     xd[k+1]=xd[k]+dt*(((c/m)*u)-(gamma*xd[k]))
 13 
 14 plt.plot(td,xd,'b-',label='approximate')

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Please, I don't need reputation or plus point or anything, I just need a help.
sorry for my bad English or bad question formatting

Comment: `u=k(r-x)` is this a multiplication?

Comment: `k` is an `int`. You're trying to call it (`k()`). That doesn't work.

Comment: @deceze so Can you please write the correct code for me? I don't know what to do :((    I will be really appreciated.

Comment: @amrrs Yes, it is u=k*(r-x)

Comment: @M.Barandov Yes, change your code like that.

Comment: @amrrs tnx,I do that but I get this error now :( 

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

in this line: 
xd[k+1]=xd[k]+dt*(((c/m)*u)-(gamma*x[dt]))

Comment: There's something wrong in using `dt` in this `(gamma*x[dt])`. Could you check that?

Comment: ```xd[k+1]=xd[k]+dt*(((c/m)*u)-(gamma*xd[k]))``` Try this!

Comment: @amrrs thank you for helping me, I don't know how should I thank you. I test that and getting new error :     

setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: @M.Barandov No Problem, Glad it was useful!

Comment: @amrrs actually it didn't solve yet. the error now is this: setting an array element with a sequence
Can you help me about this too?
I'm so sorry

Comment: Would you mind editing the question with details?

Comment: @amrrs sorry, my bad. you are right. I edit the question. tnx, a lot.

Comment: Your problem is that `u = k * (R - x)` is using `x` that is a vector. Use `u = k * (R - xd[k])`

Comment: @Adirio thanks. it works. I don't know How should I thank you. you do me a great favor. thank you. thank you. I Owe you

Comment: Ill post it as an answer. Accept it, thats the only thank you can give here.

Comment: @Adirio yes, good idea.you are right, I accept your answer, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is an array, thus `u` is an array and thus you are trying to assign an array to one of the elements. Swap `u = k * (R - x)` for `u = k * (R - xd[k])`. This way `xd[k]` is a number, thus `u` is a number too and you will be assigning a number to an element, what will give no error.